# Cannot build kivy (python 2) apk using Buildozer in MacOS [Errno socket error] [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

I'm a newbie in Kivy. My environment is as follows:
OS: MacOS v10.12.6
Kivy: using Python v2.7.10
Buildozer: v0.35dev

My main.py currently works on Kivy on my Mac and as on the Kivy Launcher on my Android phone.

When I tried to build my apk on Mac via the "buildozer android debug" command, I get the following error and log traces below. May I know how to solve this issue?

-Stephen

> ## Check configuration tokens
>
> ## Ensure build layout
>
> ## Check configuration tokens
>
> ## Preparing build
>
> ## Check requirements for android
>
> ## Search for Git (git)
>
> ## -> found at /usr/bin/git
>
> ## Search for Cython (cython)
>
> ## -> found at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/cython
>
> ## Search for Java compiler (javac)
>
> ## -> found at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac
>
> ## Search for Java keytool (keytool)
>
> ## -> found at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/keytool
>
> ## Install platform
>
> ## Run 'pip install -q --user "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10,<1.12.5" "jinja2" "six"'
>
> ## Cwd None
>
> ## Apache ANT found at /Users/cck/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
>
> ## Android SDK found at /Users/cck/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
>
> ## Android NDK found at /Users/cck/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
>
> ## Check application requirements
>
> ## Check garden requirements
>
> ## Compile platform
>
> ## Run '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>
> -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=reviseChinese --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/Users/cck/OneDrive - act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
>
> ## Cwd /Users/cck/OneDrive - act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
>
> [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a [INFO]:
>   Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI [INFO]:    Available Android
>   APIs are (19) [INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available,
>   continuing. [INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK [INFO]:    Got NDK
>   version from $ANDROIDNDKVER [INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c [INFO]:
>   Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv [INFO]:    ccache is
>   missing, the build will not be optimized in the future. [INFO]:
>   Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
>   [INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8 [WARNING]:
>   Missing executable: pkg-config is not installed [WARNING]: Missing
>   executable: autoconf is not installed [WARNING]: Missing executable:
>   automake is not installed [WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is
>   not installed [INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given
>   requirements! [INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements,
>   so one will be built. [INFO]:    Found multiple valid dependency
>   orders: [INFO]:        ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer',
>   'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy'] [INFO]:
>   ['hostpython3crystax', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf',
>   'python3crystax', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy'] [INFO]:
>   ['hostpython2', 'pygame_bootstrap_components', 'python2', 'sdl',
>   'six', 'pygame', 'pyjnius', u'kivy'] [INFO]:    Using the first of
>   these: ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf',
>   'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy'] [INFO]:    The selected
>   bootstrap is sdl2_gradle [INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2_gradle
>   bootstrap [INFO]:    Dist will have name reviseChinese and recipes
>   (kivy) [INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules () installed from pip
>   [INFO]:    -> running cp -r /Users/cck/OneDr...(and 215 more) [INFO]: 
>   -> directory context /Users/cck/OneDrive/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2 [INFO]:
>   <- directory context /Users/cck/OneDrive -
>   act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
>   [INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image',
>   'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius',
>   u'kivy'] [INFO]:    # Downloading recipes  [INFO]:    Downloading
>   hostpython2 [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/cck/One...(and 26
>   more) [INFO]:    -> directory context
>   /Users/cck/OneDrive/packages/hostpython2 [INFO]:    -> running
>   basename https://python.org/ftp...(and 34 more) [INFO]:    -> running
>   rm -f .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2                          [INFO]:
>   Downloading hostpython2 from
>   https://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2 Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",
>   line 162, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",
>   line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals   File "/Users/cck/OneDrive - act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
>   line 978, in 
>       main()   File "/Users/cck/OneDrive - act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
>   line 975, in main
>       ToolchainCL()   File "/Users/cck/OneDrive - act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
>   line 512, in **init**
>       getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)   File "/Users/cck/OneDrive -
>   act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
>   line 149, in wrapper_func
>       build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)   File "/Users/cck/OneDrive - act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
>   line 193, in build_dist_from_args
>       build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)   File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 551, in build_recipes   File
>   "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 307, in download_if_necessary
>   File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 353, in download   File
>   "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 151, in download_file   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 245, in retrieve
>       fp = self.open(url, data)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 213, in open
>       return getattr(self, name)(url)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 457, in open_https
>       return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 377, in http_error
>       result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 671, in http_error_301
>       return self.http_error_302(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data)   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 641, in http_error_302
>       data)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 667, in redirect_internal
>       return self.open(newurl)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 213, in open
>       return getattr(self, name)(url)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py",
>   line 443, in open_https
>       h.endheaders(data)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 1049, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 893, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 855, in send
>       self.connect()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 1274, in connect
>       server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py",
>   line 352, in wrap_socket
>       _context=self)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py",
>   line 579, in **init**
>       self.do_handshake()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py",
>   line 808, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake() IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version
>   (_ssl.c:590)
>
> ## Command failed: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>
> -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=reviseChinese --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/Users/cck/OneDrive - act/Desk/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build
>
> ## Buildozer failed to execute the last command
>
> ## The error might be hidden in the log above this error
>
> ## Please read the full log, and search for it before
>
> ## raising an issue with buildozer itself.
>
> ## In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your buildozer is failing to download  https://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2.  You might be able to download this package yourself and manually place it into the cache folder or wherever buildozer is putting the downloaded files so when it goes to try and download it, it will see its already there and skip over it.